# Kundera (JPA) - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, cassandra, kundera

I am trying to play around with Kundera 2.5.1 on JBoss EAP 6.1 (essentially the same as JBoss AS 7.1). However, when I deploy my application, I see the following Exception:

```
[0m[31m12:44:24,119 ERROR org.jboss.msc.service.fail MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."KunderaTests-ear.ear/KunderaTests-ejb.jar#KunderaTests": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."KunderaTests-ear.ear/KunderaTests-ejb.jar#KunderaTests": com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.0.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:103)
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:65)
at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:104)
at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:77)
at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:65)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
... 4 more
Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.findPersistenceMetadatas(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:131)
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:86)
... 11 more
```

The Kundera JARs (core & cassandra) are deployed within my EAR. There is a Web application project, and a separate EJB project that houses the entities. The persistence.xml file is in the EJB project under the src/META-INF path, but I still get this exception. I do not have any problems with other JPA providers, such as Hibernate.

My persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="KunderaTests">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9160" />
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="dev" />
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"
                value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClientFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Am I missing something? Does my configuration look okay? Or, is this an issue with deploying Kundera on JBoss EAP 6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to the latest trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kundera-discuss/x0AqH_Te6eQ.

See if it helps.

-Vivek